# length of data in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

In my Application i am Getting Json Data through ajax call from an .aspx page

json data format is like this

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "id": 911,
            "source": "Vishakhapatnam",
            "dest": "Goa",
            "capacity": 24000,
            "h1": 400,
            "h1At": 7,
            "h1Dt": 8,
            "h2": 401,
            "h2At": 9,
            "h2Dt": 9.3,
            "h3": 402,
            "h3At": 12,
            "h3Dt": 12.3,
            "h4": 403,
            "h4At": 14.3,
            "h4Dt": 15,
            "h5": 404,
            "h5At": 16,
            "h5Dt": 17,
            "h6": 405,
            "h6At": 18,
            "h6Dt": 19,
            "h7": 406,
            "h7At": 19.3,
            "h7Dt": 20,
            "h8": 407,
            "h8At": 21,
            "h8Dt": 21.3,
            "h9": 408,
            "h9At": 22,
            "h9Dt": 22.1,
            "h10": 409,
            "h10At": 23,
            "h10Dt": 24
        }
    ]
}
```

i checked this format in http://jsonlint.com/ its valid

From Javascript when i am trying to read the length of the data like this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= data.Table.length; i++)
```

`data.Table.length` returning 1 and the loop runs for once only,i don't know how to get the length of the object array inside the json data so that the loop can continue till end.

Please Help

Comment: Try to use ArrayList instead of Dataset in ur Back end..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your Table object contains an array with only one element. To get all objects you're looking for, try this instead:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= data.Table[0].length; i++)
```

Then your going inside the first element i Table and you'll get the number of children inside.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

Sorry, that's because objects don't have a length property. Please refer to this thread on StackOverflow, [jQuery ajax json response has length undefined and incorrect data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759150/jquery-ajax-json-response-has-length-undefined-and-incorrect-data)

If you want to loop all objects try this,

```
for (var obj in data.Table[0])
    console.log(obj) // Do something with your object
```

Comment: Thank you For Your replay..i have tried this one but while debugging  
in Chrome its showing 

data = Object {Table: Array[1]}


data.Table[0] = Object {id: 911, source: "Vishakhapatnam", dest: "Goa", capacity: 24000, h1: 400…}

data.Table[0].length = undefined

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the data coming from the page before you get the length of the data

by using **$.parseJson()** method i think

then the following url expalins the solution

[Reading JSON data with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186453/reading-json-data-with-jquery)